# making header print once only if true

Tags: python, formatting

I want the header to print once if the loop gets results but not print if it doesn't. I got the tip of setting the header to a True or False from here but I am trying to use it in a loop now which doesn't seem to be working.

```
header = False

if header==True:
    print('{:10} {:10}'.format('Room#','Fee'))

match_count = 0

for apt in aptList:
    if userInput >= htl.room and userInput <= htl.fee:
        header=True ## shouldnt this statement get it to print?
        print(htl.getApt())
        match_count += 1

if match_count == 0:
    header=False
```

This code does not print the header just the results. Can you not set a variable to a different value in a loop the way I did?

Comment: The header will only print when you tell it to. A previous condition won't be re-evaluated if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to print(header) after setting it to True, or in replacement of setting it to true if you only mean to print it there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will not work because you currently have a statement in the beginning defining header as `False` then the next part of the code is an if statement stating do the following if header is `True`, but you just defined it `False` in the previous statement.

So that if statement will never execute because it never goes back to check to see if header variable has changed. You have the header variable declared as `True` in the for loop, but the program never loops back to see that the if statement is now going to print the statement in the first if statement.

I would put the if statement in the for loop so it can execute it.

```
header = False
match_count = 0

for apt in aptList:
    if userInput >= htl.room and userInput <= htl.fee:
        header=True   ## shouldnt this statement get it to print?
        if header==True:
              print('{:10} {:10}'.format('Room#','Fee'))
        print(htl.getApt())
        match_count += 1

if match_count == 0:
    header=False
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it always prints the header multiple times instead of just once when I put it inside the loop.